# Shortcut for scrolling in Jupyter Notebook Docstring

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that we can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to show Docstring(documentation) in Jupter Notebook and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> again shows it in a larger pane.

But I'm wondering if it is possible to move through the Docstring (scrolling) only with keyboard buttons without using mouse.